# USB Boot iMac 4,1

Tags: usb, startup, fat32

I have a Fat32 USB that I would like to boot on my iMac 4,1.

The Mac does not recognize the device from the boot menu (option key on boot) and I have tried the Plop disk but it freezes when it says loading boot sector.

How can I get this USB to boot?

Comment: Are you using Boot Camp?

Comment: What does this have to do with booting from USB? For this issue I am trying to start a custom live CD. Which works on other computers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use Disk Utility or a 3rd Party App designed to create Bootable Disks. If using Disk Utility, you need to follow some steps to create a Boot Disk, and use the proper format (which is not FAT32 for a Mac). You should be using the HFS+ format (Mac OS Extended Journaled), and there are some additional steps you need to take to make the disk "bootable".

Cult of Mac has an excellent article on this:

http://www.cultofmac.com/180925/how-to-make-a-bootable-disk-or-usb-drive-of-os-x-mountain-lion/

FAT32 is good for having a drive that can be read/written from a PC or Mac, but you cannot boot a Mac from that format.

Comment: Thanks! I was eventually able to get it to boot. I used plop to force USB 1.1 in mode 2. Unfortunately I was not able to use my keyboard prior to the live coding starting.